# I am trying to add the Material-UI InfoIcon into my code. But I don't know how to implement it in TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add the Material-UI InfoIcon--> into my code. But I don't know how to implement it in TextField.

Here is the material-UI code:

```
      <InfoIcon fontSize="small" />
```

Here is where I want it to be:

```
   <Grid item xs={5}>
        <TextField
          id="createdate"
          label="Create Date"
          value={dateCheck(workOrderDetail.reported_date, 'll') } 
          variant="filled"
          disabled
          fullWidth
          inputProps={{ style: style.textFieldInput }}
        />
      </Grid>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to place it in textfield but get error. Is there better way to put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your icon with `InputAdornment` component. I have create a quick demo for you:

```
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InfoIcon';

<TextField
    id="createdate"
    label="Create Date"
    value={dateCheck(workOrderDetail.reported_date, 'll') } 
    variant="filled"
    disabled
    fullWidth
    InputProps={{
      style: style.textFieldInput,
      startAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          <AccountCircle />
        </InputAdornment>
      ),
    }}
/>
```

Reference: [React, Material-UI Documentation, input fields](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#with-icon)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did to make the styling correct. 
I made a function:

```
       const label = () => {
             return (
             <React.Fragment>
                Create Date <InfoIcon fontSize='small'></InfoIcon>
             </React.Fragment>
            )
       }

       <Grid item xs={5}>
        <TextField
          id="createdate"
          label={label()}
          value={dateCheck(workOrderDetail.reported_date, 'll') }
          inputProps={{ style: style.textFieldInput }}
          variant="filled"
          disabled
          fullWidth
        />
      </Grid>
```